# if else statement in my function does not work

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I have the following function:

```
function checkNumber(x){
  if(2<x<13) {
    console.log("Your number is "+x) 
  } else if (55<x<67) {
    console.log(x)
  }
}
```

When I give the function a value between 2 and 13, I want it to print "Your number is x".
When I give the function a value between 55 and 67, I want it to print my number. This function does however not work. It print "Your number is x" no matter what number I pass as argument to the function. Why?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't do comparison chaining like e.g. Python, you need `2 < x && x < 13`.

Comment: in the snippet you are  not providing any value to the function `checkNumber()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function checkNumber(x){
  if(2<x && x<13) {
    console.log("Your number is "+x) 
  } else if (55<x && x<67) {
    console.log(x)
  }
}
```